# ¿Qué significa "La puerta no se abre cuando la luz roja se ilumine"? ¿Cómo podría expresarse de mejor manera?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, sintaxis

Pocas cosas causan más fastidio a los que tratamos de hacer un uso cuidado del idioma que encontrar algo mal escrito en un medio permanente, donde el error parece hacer alarde de su existencia.

Los errores en libros son afortunadamente apenas ocasionales, mientras que en los periódicos (tanto en papel como en su formato electrónico) son harto frecuentes: faltas de ortografía, errores de redacción, fallas de puntuación, falta de sentido, etc.

Pero lo que más me irrita es encontrar algo mal escrito donde se supone que será visto y tal vez malinterpretado por muchas personas y durante mucho tiempo, como por ejemplo un cartel impreso en la vía pública, en una tienda, o, como en este caso, en un medio de transporte:

> La puerta no se abre cuando la luz roja se ilumine.

[image: Luz del tren]

Paso a explicar: en Buenos Aires hace pocos años tenemos trenes de origen chino y, si bien la mayor parte de la cartelería ha sido redactada localmente, nos encontramos a diario con este aviso que, además de no gramatical, es confuso, seguramente como resultado de una mala traducción de la lengua oriental. Debo decir que nunca he visto encenderse la luz roja (supongo que nada bueno debe anunciar) y por lo tanto no termino de entender el sentido del cartel. El desafío es:

1. ¿Qué significa para ustedes el cartel?
2. A modo de lo que sería un "edition golf", ¿cuál es el modo más claro y breve en que lo expresarían de acuerdo con el (o los) significado(s) que le atribuyan?

Comment: Una hipótesis: "ilumine" debería ser "ilumina".  Si la luz roja se ilumina, la puerta quedaría sin poderse abrir.  O sea que la luz roja indica algún problema.  ¿Por qué no preguntas a un chofer?

Comment: Creo como @aparente001 que solo se han equivocado en una letra, aunque se deberían revisar mejor estas cosas no me parece tan grave. Si vieses los carteles en euskera que hay por aquí, da para escribir un libro o dos de meteduras de pata.

Comment: Lo comenté [en Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/argentina/comments/7huap7/qu%C3%A9_significa_la_puerta_no_se_abre_cuando_la_luz/) y se ofrecieron respuestas divertidas :)

Comment: Muy buenas respuestas, por graciosas o por acertadas  Creo que ya es hora  de preguntar al conductor.

Comment: @fedorqui Me gustó especialmente la explicación de adizero (habría ganado un punto si hubiera sido usuario de este sitio): *Para mi es un tema de tiempos, "cuando la luz roja de ilumine" habla de algo futuro (el típico tono profético, no se cómo se llama). En cambio la primera parte está en presente. Ergo la frase no tiene sentido. Si se emparejan los tiempos sí suena algo más coherente: "la puerta no se abrirá cuando la luz roja se ilumine" (todo en futuro) o "la puerta no se abre si la luz roja se ilumina" (todo en presente). ...*

Comment: @fedorqui Ah, y gracias por la excelente edición de mi pregunta, que quedó mucho más clara y atractiva formulada del modo que propusiste. Realmente eres un experto en la materia. :)

Comment: @Gustavson cierto, la respuesta de adizero tiene mucho sentido común. Le he pedido que se anime a publicarla aquí :) Y nada, gracias a ti por publicar cosas interesantes. Yo formateé el título para mejorar su SEO, que es mi auténtica obsesión jaja :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo interpreto como que,  cuando y mientras la luz roja esté encendida, la puerta no podrá abrirse, seguramente por algún mecanismo de seguridad.

Una manera más correcta de decirlo seria:

> La puerta no se podrá abrir cuando la luz roja esté encendida.

Una más corta:

> Con luz roja, puerta bloqueada.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta es la que mejor responde los dos puntos. Consulté al guarda (no al chofer, sino a la persona que controla el descenso y ascenso de pasajeros y la apertura y el cierre de puertas) y me explicó que la luz roja se enciende cuando hay que hacer una evacuación. Se bloquean todas las puertas y sólo queda alguna habilitada para la evacuación.

Answer (score 4):

Yo entiendo que el cartel dice que:

> cuando la luz roja se enciende, la puerta no puede abrirse

Una mejor forma de redactarlo seria:

> La puerta permanece bloqueada mientras la luz roja esta iluminada

Answer (score 3):

Yo pondría lo siguiente:

> La luz roja indica que la puerta está bloqueada.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.Se. Normalmente en las respuestas no solemos simplemente "dar una solución", sino que **explicamos** el porqué de la misma. Por qué piensas que ese es el sentido de la frase original? Por qué piensas que esa es la mejor o una correcta traducción. Si ves otras preguntas y respuestas, se centran en **responder realmente a la pregunta**, tratando de explicar y razonar la respuesta. Eso es lo que distingue a las buenas respuestas. Bienvenido de nuevo. No dudes en pedir ayuda con la funcionalidad del sitio si la necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the spirit of your second point about a "golf" version how about

> Luz roja, puerta cerrada

Comment: Thank you for your effort to produce a brief version. Even though your rendering was the shortest, I find the comma and the word "cerrada" (instead of "bloqueada", as the doors are usually closed but are **locked** when the red light turns on) to be inaccurate. With the comma, I prefer walen's version: *Con luz roja, puerta bloqueada* or, based on Ashes's proposal, *Luz roja indica puerta bloqueada*.

Answer (score 1):

Consultado en Reddit, recibí [una respuesta la mar de interesante](https://www.reddit.com/r/argentina/comments/7huap7/qu%C3%A9_significa_la_puerta_no_se_abre_cuando_la_luz/dqu46kh/):

> Para mi es un tema de tiempos, "cuando la luz roja de ilumine" habla de algo futuro (el típico tono profético, no se cómo se llama). En cambio la primera parte está en presente. Ergo la frase no tiene sentido.
>
> Si se emparejan los tiempos sí suena algo más coherente: "la puerta no se abrirá cuando la luz roja se ilumine" (todo en futuro) o "la puerta no se abre si la luz roja se ilumina" (todo en presente). Arreglado lo de los tiempos, sacaría lo de ilumine, es redundante (la luz está encendida, ya sabemos que ilumina). Y también lo de no se abre, para eso decimos puerta cerrada. Algo como "la puerta permanecerá cerrada cuando se encienda la luz roja" me parece mejor.

Comment: Es precisamente la respuesta que, por su lucidez, destaqué en mi comentario de Dec 9 at 14:33.

Comment: @Gustavson exactamente. Le comenté a su autor si quería publicarla aquí y dijo que no, pero que lo hiciera yo si quería. Así lo hice, para que "quede en acta".